# What does Krillin's "Tacos" shirt refer to?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, japanese-language

In *Dragon Ball Super*, Krilin wears a t-shirt with the word "Tacos" on it. What does it mean? Is it the Mexican "tacos" food, or is it the Japanese "takos" (which means octopuses, which are eaten in Japan, and may also be spelt "tacos") or is it something else?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I would say it's definitely one out of these 3 possibilities,

- It refers to the Japanese word *Tako*, ie "Octopus". This word is also a cheeky way of referring to someone's baldness (Example: Tatsumaki uses this word to insult Saitama in One Punch Man(Where the Main character's baldness is a recurring joke)). Krillin's baldness has been made fun of in the show. So this could possibly be a reason for the same.
- The Mexican dub of Dragon Ball Z was very popular and considered to be one of the best. So perhaps it could be Toei acknowledging them as a fanbase considering they chose *"Tacos"* in specific when they could've possibly put anything else on his shirt.
- Perhaps we are thinking too much of it. Just like in countries like the U.S where we see T-shirts with random Japanese Kanji on it, T-Shirts with random English words are indeed popular in Japan. So it was probably randomly chosen.

Personally, I would like to think they gave it some thought and it was perhaps chosen on account of the first reason. However, it could very likely be for absolutely no reason at all and something only the artists know.

Comment: As far as I know, tako is more a general insult than one specifically about baldness.